# SQL выбрать числа с точкой если таких нет, то округлить и выбрать целое

Tags: sql

Доброго времени.

В таблице следующие числовые значения:

```
33.33
33
```

Есть ли такой формат данных SQL при котором запрос вида:

```
SELECT WHERE 33.33
```

будет выводить и 33.33 и 33?
Что-то типа автоокругления до целого.

РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t=33.33 OR t=FLOOR(33.33)
```

Спасибо.

Comment: а почему условие не сделать TRUNCATE(x,0)=TRUNCATE(33.33,0)? либо ROUND() если в ближ сторону.

Comment: ну да можно дополнительно добавить OR и округлять значение через ROUND(), но мне почему то казалось что есть именно формат данных который автоматьм выбирает целые числа при вводе чисел с точкой.

Comment: В SQL такого нет, и замечу, что этого вообще нет нигде в программировании. Либо значение автоматически округляется, если тип данных в сравнении целый и тогда ищутся только целые значения, либо не округляется и берется как есть.

Comment: решил так SELECT * FROM t WHERE t=33.33 OR t=FLOOR(33.33)

Comment: Вынесите Ваше решение в ответ и примите его как верный.

Answer (score 3):

Поможет использование EXISTS

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.column <> TRUNC(t.column) OR
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column <> TRUNC(t2.column))
```

Теперь подробнее.

t.column <> TRUNC(t.column) - trunc отбрасывает дробную часть в числе. В данном случае мы проверим что число не является целым.

NOT EXISTS - проверка на наличие в таблице дробных значений.Если их нет, то возвращаем все записи из таблицы.

Comment: Какой то странный запрос который возвращает : все дробные числа  или если дробных нет, то все числа.

Comment: Возможно я не правильно понял задачу. Но в шапке запроса как раз и указано: выбрать числа с точкой, если таких нет то целые.

Comment: в пояснении есть указание что хочу округлять до целого.

Comment: Значит все же не так понял. Виноват. Просто я притянул пояснения к вопросу, а в данном случае нужно было делать наоборот.